# ET Geotools Split Lines at Vertices Issue

Tags: arcgis-desktop, line, splitting, et-geowizards

This might seem like a really simple question but for whatever reason I can't figure it out. How do I run the split line tool in ET Geotools on an entire polyline layer? I can do it for a single feature within the layer but I am unsure of how to apply it to the entire layer.

Comment: In Editing Mode Ctrl+A (Select All) and then the Split Lines All Vertices http://www.ian-ko.com/ET_GeoTools/UserGuide/ETSplitPolylineTools.htm

Comment: Doesn't seem to work? I can select all features but split line tool doesn't seem to do anything, however I select one feature then use the tool it works.

Answer (score 1):

In ET_Geotools, in section of polyline you will find split line but use this tool after stopping your editing and follow the instructions as well as you seeing. This tool can split entire layer in a single time.

In Editing Mode Ctrl+A (Select All) and then the Split Lines All Vertices ian-ko.com/ET_GeoTools/UserGuide/ETSplitPolylineTools.htm